# How to Retrieve 1 Result from Custom MySQL fetch Function

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

Yesterday another user helped out with building a generic function for handling MySQL Queries. It looks like this:

```
function fetchAll($query) {
  $res = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
  $a   = array();
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
        $a[]=$row;
    }
  }
  return $a;
}
```

And to output the returned results I simply do the following:

```
$data = fetchAll("SELECT * FROM news_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");

foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

My question relates to outputting the result when there's only one result in the array. Like when displaying the current blog post of a page. I want to know if I can do it without first calling the foreach loop? Is there a way to output just the first result from the array as I do not need to loop through it.

Perhaps I could have an alternate function, as opposed to the fetchAll() one above? One that just outputs one row?

Cheers,

Scott

Comment: why don't you limit your query by 1 ?

Comment: And don't use direct queries. Build them. Otherwise it's unsecure.

Comment: Even if I LIMIT 1, it still won't return a value unless I loop through with a foreach. @Corbin, I would like to know how to create a fetchOne() function as you suggest!

Comment: Just return the value of mysql_fetch_assoc instead of building an array.  I say this trying to be helpful, not mean, but you might should consider revisiting the basics of the language.

Comment: @Corbin, Oh don't get me wrong. I have used the standard functions for over a decade now. I have just been wanting to play around with more streamlined methods for fetching data (without PDO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example:

```
echo $data[0]['title'];
```

Basically your $data is a two-dimensional array, with the first dimension being the row number (count starts with 0), so you can access any of the rows directly if you know its number. If you only have one row, it's necessarily 0.

Comment: Lovely thank you!! Makes sense. It's not as pretty as just echo $data['title']; but it will do - and the benefits of this function I am using mean a lot less lines of code. So it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Just count the array

```
 if(count($data) == 1) {
     // Only one dataset
 } else if(count($data) > 0) {
     // foreach
 } else {
     // no content
 }
```

Comment: foreach will fail if count($data) === 0

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $data[0]['title'];
```

Should print exactly what your looking for. In 2D arrays the first dimension is the array index and as array index start at 0, the above code will echo the first row in that array.

Comment: Thanks Darren. Looks like you and the poster above agree. By any chance, would there be a better function to use if Im just trying to retrieve one row only?

Comment: Although not the most aesthetically appealing the answer you have accepted is the best.